# How to find function name and print it in which in the variable is declared in c

Tags: c

```
int findme()
{

    int input[120];
    int make00;
}
```

I want to find make00 in the program and after finding i want to print the function name which contain this variable. How do I do that PS:I am noob in c.(linux)

Comment: @AntoJurković I need function name in which variable is declared -_-

Comment: This is a *really* complicated task. It depends entirely on your environment, and requires that debugging information be enabled in your build: Windows (PE + PDB), Linux (ELF + DWARF), embedded (screwed).

Comment: Find in source code or in resulting binary? If first, use C parser (e.g. clang) to parse full code and find there whatever you need. If latter, it is not possible/unreliable unless full debugging symbols enabled.

Comment: Note that in general, the same variable name may appear in many functions and source files that are part of the same program.  Why do you think you need to do this?  Are you writing a debugger?

Comment: I am making makefile generator that should automatically make the makefile in linux @JonathanLeffler

Comment: What makefile have to do with variable names?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered good old `bison + flex`? The C/C++ grammar could be very simplified for your needs... I think this is your best option here.